# Allow users of my profile based site to embed their twitter feeds without allowing <script> tags?

Tags: twitter

Im making a site where users create profiles. I want users to be able to embed their twitter feeds on their profile page for others to see.

Im using a CMS but I want the posts to be pulled on the front end. I dont want the posts to be content thats imported into the CMS. I also need it to be easy for users to set up their feeds, ideally by just entering their usernames into the CMS.

With facebook its easy to achieve this with the likebox (users can embed pages not personal profiles). The likebox uses the code below, and the CMS swaps out FACEBOOK-NAME for the user's page's facebook name.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="FACEBOOK-NAME" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

However I havnt been able to do the same thing with twitter. Here USERNAME is only used to create the link back to twitter. Im assuming the number 400306334253318144 is the user's ID of some sort, but you also have to enable the widget within twitter.com.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/USERNAME" data-widget-id="400306334253318144">Tweets by @USERNAME</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Is there any solution that will allow users to embed their twitter feed by just providing their username or twitter url?

If they do need to enable the widget in twitter.com then thats not the end of the world. But is there a simpler way of then embedding a feed? I dont want to allow `<script>` tags for user generated content in my CMS for security reasons.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same requirements